# Disable current date and +31 days from the current day but Enables after the 31 days - datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable current and future 31 days from date.

Right now I can only get it to disable specific dates but not what I actually need. I am using below code to disable to the dates.

I would really appreciate the help if possible.

```
var dates = []; 
function DisableDates(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
    return [dates.indexOf(string) == -1];
}
$(function() {
     $("#date").datepicker({
         beforeShowDay: DisableDates
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`minDate` option](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) with the `Number` type:

> **Number**: A number of days from today. For example `2` represents two days from today and `-1` represents yesterday.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker({
    minDate: 31,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-ELV+xyi8IhEApPS/pSj66+Jiw+sOT1Mqkzlh8ExXihe4zfqbWkxPRi8wptXIO9g73FSlhmquFlUOuMSoXz5IRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<input id="date"/>
```